# How can we write KVL in a MOSFET gate source loop if no current flows?

Tags: mosfet

[image: biased mosfet]

In the attached image, there is a MOSFET with the bias conditions.

I am not able to understand how we write a KVL equation as V<sub>0</sub> = V<sub>gs</sub> + I<sub>d</sub>·R<sub>s</sub> as there isn't any current through the gate. How does V<sub>0</sub> change with V<sub>gs</sub>?

Comment: Voltages (potential differences) can exist without current flowing. A battery doesn't stop having a voltage across its terminals just because you're not drawing any current from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You raise an interesting point. For some reason I never really considered applying KVL to any loop containing a gate-drain or gate-source element.

That's probably because since the gate of a MOSFET (or reverse biased JFET gate junction) draws no current or so little current that it's negligible, you don't really need to.

In fact, we are usually taught that all you need to know is the potential ***at*** the gate (with respect to the FET's source, of course) in order to know the state of the FET's channel.

To calculate the gate's potential, it's common to treat the gate as open-circuit, where there's no actual "loop" to apply KVL to! However, you are right to ask the question, because the gate-to-source nodes do indeed form part of a loop, to which KVL *can* be applied.

If we assume the that the impedance looking into the gate is infinite (which is not true, and I'll talk about that in a moment), then anything you connect that gate to doesn't even know the gate is there. The presence of gate-and-source (or gate-and-drain) connected across any other element or combination of elements, be they resistors, other transistors, cells, or whatever with a potential difference, might look like these:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwgqL2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

KVL applied to the loop containing the gate always yields this equation:

$$ V_{GS} = V_{AB} $$

Since the gate draws no current, it doesn't have any influence on any other part of the circuit. You don't need to include the gate between G and S in any analysis, all you need is to perform analyses to establish the potentials at A and B, ignoring the MOSFET completely.

Also, since \$I_G = 0A\$, we don't even need to consider Kirchhoff's Current Law. Clearly when \$R_{GATE} = \infty \$, these KVL and KCL equations are redundant. Knowing \$V_{AB}\$ is sufficient to know \$V_{GS}\$, and that is sufficient to determine channel state.

Having said all that, the truth is that \$R_{GATE} \ne \infty\$. In order for the FET's channel state to be a function of \$V_{GS}\$, some energy *must* be derived from the gate-side of the FET to affect its channel, between source and drain. Some work *must* be done.

In reality, to evacuate or populate the drain-source channel with charge carriers that participate in channel conduction, the isolated gate itself must have an absence or accumulation of charge too. Anything connected to the gate must therefore provide those charges, or remove them, requiring that work be done, that energy be transferred, on the gate-side. Work must also be done at the gate.

The property we associate with the "holding of an electric charge" is capacitance, and the gate, to everything that's connected to it, looks exactly like a small capacitance. The work that I talk of is simply the charging or discharging of that gate capacitance. The energy stored in this capacitance is the "work done". Those above circuits would, in reality look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvrayP.png)</sup>

For low frequency signals, the impedance of capacitance \$C_{GATE}\$ is so high that you can probably disregard it completely, but as gate signal frequency increases, the influence of \$C_{GATE}\$ becomes more and more significant.

At higher frequencies, we cannot ignore \$C_{GATE}\$, and while the KVL equation for the loop A,B,S,G is still \$V_{GS} = V_{AB}\$, we can't ignore the fact that \$I_G \ne 0A\$. It is Kirchhoff's Current Law that becomes of concern, and you will need to apply KCL to the gate node in order to account for the influence of the gate's inherent capacitance.

Comment: Note also that "higher frequencies" includes fast switching. Gate drivers for power MOSFETs frequently drive amps of current, sometimes tens of amps, into the gate capacitance to turn it on and off very quickly, even if the actual switching frequency is low, in order to minimize losses associated with the FET being in linear mode. You can need quite a lot of current, because the kinds of FETs used for that purpose can have very high gate capacitance--as much as tens of nanofarads.